# r bump/slope chart set custom thickness and color

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider a dataframe as follows, which has 5 items that were ranked at 3 time points

```
item<-rep(c(1:5),3)
time<-rep(c('a','b','c'),15)
rank<-round(runif(15,2,10),1)
stack<-as.data.frame(cbind(item,time,rank))
```

looks something like

```
  item time rank
1    1    a  3.2
2    2    b  4.8
3    3    c  5.6
4    4    a  9.6
5    5    b  2.1
6    1    c  6.6
```

I plot it like this

```
ggplot(data = stack, aes(x = time, y = rank, group = item)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = item, alpha = 1), size=2 )+
  geom_point(aes(color = item, alpha = 1), size = 4)
```

[image]

There are a few ways I want to manipulate this graph:

1. I would like to be able to show the magnitude of changes by size of
   the line, so that thicker lines represent bigger changes, but I want to do this for each time point a-b and b-c
2. I would like to show the same through color, where a positive change is a green line and a negative change is a red line, again this should be by each timepoint a-b, b-c

so far I have only been able to change the overall color or thickness, not by intervals a-b, and b-c

any other ideas of representing level of change are welcome (alpha is an option).

Comment: For anyone else looking, I found https://ibecav.github.io/slopegraph/ as a really good package for making nice slope graphs using the 'newggslopegraph' function.

Answer (score 1):

First, made a quick change to your sample data to make it fully reproducible.

```
item<-factor(rep(c(1:5),3))
time<-rep(c('a','b','c'),15)
rank<-round(runif(15,2,10),1)
stack<-data.frame(item,time,rank)
```

You can manipulate colour and size of the connecting line by calculating those values and adding them as an aesthetic. For example

```
library(dplyr)
stack <- stack %>% 
  group_by(item) %>% 
  mutate(delta = rank-lag(rank),
         direction =  ifelse(delta >  0, "Positive","Negative"))
```

If you wanted to use relative difference instead of absolute difference, you can modify the above easily.

```
ggplot(stack, aes(x = time, y = rank, colour = direction, group = item)) +
  geom_line(aes(size = delta)) +
  geom_point(colour = "black") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("green","red"))
```

[image]
Which does what you looked to do, but is admittedly kind of hideous. You can play around with colours and sizes until you get something you are happy with, or use alpha as an accepted aes, but overall I'd suggest thinking of an alternative. The objective of a bump chart is to make it easy to follow the changes in relative position across multiple periods or dimensions. By changing colour and size with direction, you're actually making it more difficult to track which line you're on as you go through time. I think your initial approach made more visual sense. Adjusting that slightly, you get something like this:

```
ggplot(stack, aes(x = time, y = rank, group = item)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = item)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = item), size = 4) +
  geom_point(colour = "black", pch = 1, size = 4) +
  geom_label(data = stack %>% 
               filter(time == "c"),aes(label = item,
                                       fill = item)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Rank")
```

[image]

Comment: eesh, that does look absolutely hideous! But thank you for showing me it is possible. The second option does look better.

Comment: before I accept, I just realized the time and item do not make sense, instead it should have been time<-rep(c('a','b','c'),each=5). When I do this and use your code, the first lines do not appear. Any suggestions? Pretty new to dplyr